# Maximum call size exceeded when signing up user with Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, object, registration

I'm trying to set up user authentication for a website with Firebase. That works successfully. But after registering the user I want to add an entry to the firebase realtime database with all my other info related to that user (because firebase auth only allows email and password).

This is my registerUser(uid) function that gets called when I successfully register a user with firebase authentication:

```
function registerUser(uid) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  var surname = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var category = document.querySelector('.category').lastChild;
  var categoryText = category.options[category.selectedIndex].text;

  var utente;
  if (categoryText === "Studente") {
    utente = new Studente(name, surname, email);
    const utenteJSON = JSON.stringify(utente);
    set(ref(db, "Users/" + uid), {
      Studente: utenteJSON,
    })
      .then(() => {
        window.location.href = "viewInserisciMetodoPagamento.html";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      })
  } else {
    console.log("shown");
    utente = new Ascoltatore(name, surname, email);
    console.log("not shown");
    const utenteJSON = JSON.stringify(utente);
    set(ref(db, "Users/" + uid), {
      Ascoltatore: utenteJSON,
    })
      .then(() => {
        window.location.href = "viewInserisciMetodoPagamento.html";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      })
  }
}
```

The issue only exists when the user selects the "Ascoltatore" category from a dropdown select during sign up. In fact, in the else statement, you can see where the code stops executing.

Ascoltatore is an Object definition class that I created for better-storing user data.

```
import User from './User.js';

export default class Studente extends User {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, email, metodiPagamento = [], titoliStudioList = [], /*materieCompetenzaList = []*/) {
        super(firstName, lastName, email, metodiPagamento);
        this._titoliStudioList = titoliStudioList;
        /*this._materieCompetenzaList = materieCompetenzaList;*/
    }

    get titoliStudioList() {
        return this._titoliStudioList;
    }

    set titoliStudioList(titoloStudio) {
        this._titoliStudioList.push(titoloStudio);
    }

    /* get _materieCompetenzaList() {
         return this._materieCompetenzaList;
     }
 
     set _materieCompetenzaList(materia) {
         this._materieCompetenzaList.push(materia);
     }*/
}
```

The whole process will work if I comment out the materieCompetenzaList field like I did above. But it won't when it's there.

Why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

There is a name collision there. inside the getter of `_materieCompetenzaList` you are referring to `this._materieCompetenzaList` which calls the getter again and so on.

To remedy this, rename one of them. It would make sense to remove the `_` from the getter and setter names.